Dynamic Prev in Kusto (KQL)
I have a table with Dates, Tickers, And Strategies for multiple stocks. I'd like to create a revised strategy column that pulls the most recent strategy per ticker that isn't equal to "Flat". How could this be accomplished? I've tried serializing and used the prev function with no luck. Here's an example of my data:
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------+
|  Date  | Ticker | Strategy | RevisedStrategy |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------+
| 1-Jan  | A      | Short    | Short           |
| 2-Jan  | B      | Long     | Long            |
| 3-Jan  | A      | Flat     | Short           |
| 15-Mar | A      | Short    | Short           |
| 1-Jun  | B      | Flat     | Long            |
| 15-Jun | A      | Flat     | Short           |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------------+


Could you share what you have tried?


I'd like to create a revised strategy column that pulls the most recent strategy per ticker that isn't equal to "Flat". How could this be accomplished?

You can use below KQL Query to get revised strategy based on most recent ticker that isn't equal to Flat:
let ri_dta = datatable(DateTime: datetime, Ticker: string, Strategy: string)
[
    datetime(2023-01-01), "A", "Short",
    datetime(2023-01-02), "B", "Long",
    datetime(2023-01-03), "A", "Flat",
    datetime(2023-03-15), "A", "Short",
    datetime(2023-06-01), "B", "Flat",
    datetime(2023-06-15), "A", "Flat"
];
let r_nfs = ri_dta
    | where Strategy != "Flat"
    | project DateTime, Ticker, RNFS = Strategy
    | summarize arg_max(DateTime, *) by Ticker
    | project DateTime, Rec_NFS = RNFS,Ticker;
ri_dta
| join kind = leftouter (r_nfs ) on Ticker
| project DateTime, Ticker, Strategy, New_Strategy = iif(Strategy != "Flat", Strategy, Rec_NFS)

Output:

Fiddle.
